Имеет ли смысл запускать несколько копий приложения на разных портах?
Имеет ли смысл делать несколько точек запуска приложения (например поднять на нескольких портах) и потом их указывать в upstream у NGINX или этим занимается UWSGI в параметре processes?

А в чём должен быть этот смысл?

Думаю, чтобы нагрузку снижал при пиковых нагрузках

Обычно используют gunicorn или другой веб-сервер, он запускает приложение в нескольких процессах (воркерах), и все крутится на одном порту. Если уже при таком варианте производительности не хватает, тогда уже нужно будет думать - разносить вообще на отдельные машины, например, и как-то балансировать нагрузку.

@insolor ну в теории вроде uwsgi должен работать аналогично

Правильно пишут, если корова одна, то хоть передом её ставь, хоть задом, будет полведра молока и не больше. Современные ОС достаточно умны, чтоб самостоятельно распараллеливать процессы. Кроме того, я б ещё хотел увидеть приложение, написанное на Питоне, которое тупит. Если ну очень ёмкая математика типа факториалы для миллионов, я б ещё понял смысл этой возни.

ну в теории же если мы поднимаем несколько VDS, затем ставим NGINX и он потом отправляет на работающий сервис запросы. Просто в чем смысл запуска 2го VDS с такими же настройками, если можно поднять 2ой сервис на этой же VDS и через NGINX в upstream сделать балансировку? (ну я сейчас не учитываю тот параметр, что если VDS упал, то все накроется медным унитазом) Я просто смотрю на это как балансировку через сервисы. Или как я написал выше тоже самое делает параметр process в конфиге uwsgi?
